# Does a Korg Microkey Air work over Android Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Their website documentation stated that *operation is not guaranteed*. Was there a known instance that it did work or not? I've seen this product works in IOS Bluetooth and Bluetooth is supposed to be product agnostic. So I don't understand why *operation is not guaranteed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the below information from a friend:

> Well, it seems the keyboard supports Android just fine.
>
> From this([https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B01IP4ENCS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01IP4ENCS)) page: "I
> held off buying this keyboard for a long time because I read comments
> that said it did not work with Android. But that is not correct (at
> least in 2019) ... the keyboard works just fine with Android over
> Bluetooth. I tested with Android 8 and up, using the app FluidSynth
> (which allows you to use downloadable sf2 soundfont files).
>
> The only tip: you must connect to LE Bluetooth from inside the
> Fluidsynth app, not from Android's system."
>
> And this(https://pianopenguin.net/best-bluetooth-midi-keyboard/) page:
> "This simply means that you can connect it with any Mac, Android or
> Windows device that uses Bluetooth."

Therefore, this proves enough that the Korg microKEY Air does work on Android Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to install the app "MIDI+BTLE" first. Then I had to do the following sequence each time I want to play.

1. Put microKEY Air in "wireless mode".
2. Start MIDI+BTLE app.
3. Select **START BLUETOOTH SCAN**.
4. When **microKEY2-37** shows up, select it.
5. Start FluidSynth.
6. When the **MIDI output port not connected** shows up, select it.
7. Select microKEY2-37 Air shows up, select it.
8. Tap elsewhere to dismiss the modal dialog.
9. By default the microKEY Air transmits on midi channel 1. Apparently you can use the Korg Kontrol Windows or Mac app to change this and other settings.

I was able to download SoundFont files from

https://musical-artifacts.com/?apps=fluidsynth&formats=sf2&license=free&order=top_rated&tags=soundfont

Hope this helps.

Cross posted to [korgforums.com](http://www.korgforums.com/forum/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=831126#831126).